# jQuery scrollTop through anchors preserving browser history

Tags: jquery, browser-history, scrolltop

I'm trying to add smooth transitions between a page anchors.

In the following code, transitions are working but browser history do not remember the anchor navigation. Using browser back button fails. Removing `preventDefault()` make everything works, but the page flashes with the target tag content before scrolling to it from the previous page position.

I have tried plugins — like [address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/docs/) — without success. So, what is the easy way to scroll through anchors preserving browser history?

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop: $(href).offset().top}, 'slow', 'swing'
  );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427965/jquery-smooth-scroll-issue-on-safari-mac-os). The answer implies a nice jQuery library: [smoothanchors](https://github.com/alextrob/SmoothAnchors).

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
    $("html,body").animate({
```

with this

```
    $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({
```

It's also good practice to use different variable names from other values e.g. HREF used for variable name and is also the link attribute.